# Part after # is missing from the request parameter value

Tags: java, servlets, query-string

I did a hello world web application in Java on Tomcat container. I have a query string

```
code=askdfjlskdfslsjdflksfjl#_=_
```

with underscores on both sides of `=` in the URL. When I tried to retrieve the query string in the servlet by `request.getParameter("code")`, I get only `askdfjlskdfslsjdflksfjl`. The part after `#` is missing.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Yes, anchor values are not transmitted to the server, they are handled by the browser.

Answer (score 5):

That's because the part of the url after # is not a part of the query.

[Section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) of approprate RFC says:

> The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI.

Comment: so i cannot send the # or _ character in the query string?

Comment: as @fonini said, you have to encode it http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt says so). For example encoded #  is %23

Comment: @user1098255 here's an online utility that can help http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Answer (score 1):

The # is only interpreted by the browser, not the server. If you want to pass the # character to the server, you must URLEncode it.

Example:

```
URLEncoder.encode("code=askdfjlskdfslsjdflksfjl#=", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: for example i typed the url www.oauth.com/?code="sdfsdfsdf#_=_"

Comment: i believe URLEncoder can be used to send the request through java,here i just typed in the browser the url www.oauth.com/?code="sdfsdfsdf#_=_

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [percent encoding on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters). The `#` and `=` are [reserved characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters) in URLs. Only unreserved characters can be used plain in URLs, all other characters are supposed to be [URL-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters). The URL-encoded value of a `#` is `%23` and `=` is `%3D`. So this should do:

```
code=askdfjlskdfslsjdflksfjl%23_%3D_
```

If this actually originates from a HTML `<a>` link in some JSP like so:

```html
<a href="servletUrl?code=askdfjlskdfslsjdflksfjl#_=_">some link</a>
```

then you should actually have changed it to use [JSTL's](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<c:url>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html):

```html
<c:url var="servletUrlWithParam" value="servletUrl">
    <c:param name="code" value="askdfjlskdfslsjdflksfjl#_=_" />
</c:url>
<a href="${servletUrlWithParam}">some link</a>
```

so that it get generated as

```html
<a href="servletUrl?code=askdfjlskdfslsjdflksfjl%23_%3D_">some link</a>
```

Note that this is not related to Java/Servlets per-se, this applies to every web application.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am getting this parameter from a third party site that is they are sending me this url with this code so i think there is no way to change it :)

Comment: If you think of some alternatives please let me know.

Comment: It's the third party site's mistake. You need to tell them to fix it. Or, if it is **actually** a callback URL (in other words, you've actually created the desired URL *yourself*), then you need to fix it accordingly using `URLEncoder#encode()` before giving the callback URL to the 3rd party site.